# Java return type of MySQL 'ENCODE' and 'DECODE' Functions

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

So I'm using JPA (Eclipselink as the provider) for persistence in a project of mine. I know a MySQL Function:

```
SELECT ENCODE('text','key');
```

This encodes the string 'text' using 'key'. And to decode it, I use its counterpart

```
SELECT DECODE('****','key');
```

Where '****' is the result of the encoding in the first function. I require these functions to encode and decode certain columns on my database.
I would like to use these functions in JPA and I thought of a clever way to do so using native queries. But casting the result of either function to String always throws an Exception saying I cannot cast whatever object was returned to a String. What data type do these functions return? Is there another alternative to encode a column in the database without having to do this?

Comment: Have you checked the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encode)?

Comment: "The result is a binary string of the same length as str."

Comment: I have. Unfortunately, there's nothing specific to any programming language. But using these functions in SQLyog seems to return a string (or what looks like it).